# Find duplicate element in a vector and add the quantity. Code or algorithm are welcome

Tags: c++

I have a struct:

```
struct fruit_t
{
    char fruit_name[MAX_LENGTH];  // name of fruit
    float quantity; // in lbs
    float price;          // price tag of the fruit
};
```

Here is how I store my data in main

```
vector<fruit_t> fruit;

ifstream inFile;
int count = 0;
inFile.open("list1.txt");                                      
int i = 0;
while (true){                                     
    fruit.push_back(fruit_t());
    inFile >> fruit[i].fruit_name;
    inFile >> fruit[i].quantity;
    inFile >> fruit[i].price;
    if (inFile.eof() ) break;                           
    i++;
    count++;
}
```

Then I need to make a program to find duplicate `fruit_name`. If it is duplicate, add their quantity together
Here is my file (I used array_list aka `vector` to store the data)

```
//fruit_name       quantity  price
melon_cantaloupe     2.60     2.99
apples_gala          1.80     1.21
bananas              2.88     0.49
oranges_naval        2.63     0.99
apples_gala          3.00     1.21
raspberries          4.76     3.25
apples_gala          1.45     1.21
mango                4.07     1.20
blueberries          3.85     2.50
oranges_honeybell    4.20     1.08
apples_jazz          4.39     2.69
oranges_honeybell    4.22     1.08
```

This is the output if the program worked:

```
//fruit_name       quantity  price
apples_gala          6.25     1.21
apple_jazz           4.39     2.69
bananas              2.88     0.49
...
```

Comment: You'll need to search your whole vector whenever deciding to add a new fruit.  If you find the fruit in there, then update the quantity.  A smarter way would be to build an index using `std::unordered_map` or similar so you can find the fruit quicker.  Note that one slight giveaway with the "desired" output is that it's in alphabetical order.  This suggests that perhaps the fruits are stored as a `std::map` instead.  You can use `std::string` as the key, and there would be no need to store the name inside `fruit_t` at all...  `std::map<std::string, fruit_t>`

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<fruit_t> cpy; 
for (int i = 0; i < fruit.length(); i++) {
     bool already_entered = false;
       
      for (int j = 0; j < cpy.length(); j++) {
          bool diff = false;
          for (int k = 0; k < MAX_LENGTH; k++) {
             if (cpy[j].fruit_name[k] != fruit[i].fruit_name[k]) {
                   diff = true;
             }
          }
          if (diff == false) {
            already_entered = true;
          }
      }
        
      if (already_entered == true) {
          continue;
      }
       
      float new_quantity = fruit[i].quantity;
      for (int j = i + 1; j < fruit.length(); j++) {
          bool diff = false;
          for (int k = 0; k < MAX_LENGTH; k++) {
             if (fruit[j].fruit_name[k] != fruit[i].fruit_name[k]) {
                   diff = true;
             }
          }
          if (diff == false) {
              new_quantity += fruit[j].quantity;
          }
       }
        
       cpy.push_back(fruit_t());
       for (int k = 0; k < MAX_LENGTH; k++) cpy[cpy.length() - 1].fruit_name[k] = fruit[i].fruit_name[k];
       cpy[cpy.length() - 1].quantity = new_quantity;
       cpy[cpy.length() - 1].price = fruit[i].price;
 }
```

What this does:
We create a new vector that will only have once occurrence of each fruit name.

We loop through our original vector, each time checking if we have already processed the current fruit (we can do this by simply looping through our cpy array). Now, we loop through the rest of the vector with a nested for loop, and add to our new_quantity variable the sum of quantities that appear for that fruit later in our original vector. Finally, we create a new object and store our results in cpy.

Comment: The field `fruit_name` is a C style string (`char` array), you can't compare them for equality this way. They also aren't assignable so `cpy[cpy.length() - 1].fruit_name = fruit[i].fruit_name` won't work.

Comment: @Blastfurnace my bad, i thought that it was a string at first... it should be fixed now.

Comment: Hint: `strcmp()` and `strcpy()` are the functions you want.

Answer (score 0):

You might sort input, and then accumulate consecutive group:

```
auto less_by_name = [](const fruit_t& lhs, const fruit_t& rhs) {
    return strcmp(lhs.fruit_name, rhs.fruit_name) < 0;
}
std::sort(fruit.begin(), fruit.end(), less_by_name);

for (auto it = fruit.begin(); it != fruit.end(); /*empty*/) {
    auto next = std::find_if(it, fruit.end(),
                             [=](const fruit_t& f){
                                 return less_by_name(it->fruit_name, f.fruit_name); });
    // close-open range [it-next) has similar elements
    auto quantity = std::accumulate(it, next, 0.f,
                                    [](float acc, const fruit_t& f){ return acc + f.quantity; })
    std::cout << it->fruit_name << " " << quantity << std::endl;
    it = next;
}
```

Note: From the above, we ignore price, you probably want to merge fruits only with same name **and** price. You have then to adapt `less_by_name`.